# can Keras image_dataset_from_directory input two labels per image?

Tags: user-input, tf.keras, multilabel-classification

Trying to predict two categories of an image (say: number of people in it (0 to 9) and state of the weather (sunny, cloudy, raining)). How to input two labels (say: y1 = 6, y2 = 1) or (y1=6, y2="cloudy") per image?
I am using  image_dataset_from_directory, which works for single labels, and I do not know what will happen if I direct it to a list with pairs of labels.